# access different users login in php

Tags: php

I have created login form with php code , And it works fine but I am trying to multiple access for different users.I added new column in my users table (user_type) and I have already read the topic in this website but unfortunately does not help . 
this is my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  
  
</head>
<body>
 <?PHP
        include ('header.php');
        include ('setting.php');
        session_start();
    ?>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <h4 style="border-bottom: 1px solid #c5c5c5;">
    <i class="fa fa-h-square" style="font-size:24px"></i>
    Account Access for Hospital member
  </h4>
  <div style="padding: 20px;" id="form-olvidado">
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" id="login-form" action="hospital_signin.php" method="post">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            @
          </span>
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="UserName" name="username"  required="" autofocus="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock">
            </i>
          </span>
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
            Login
          </button>
          <p class="help-block">
            <a class="pull-right text-muted" href="hospital_signup.php" id="olvidado"><small>New User</small></a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
  
</div>
 </div>
</div>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#olvidado').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div#form-olvidado').toggle('500');
  });
  $('#acceso').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div#form-olvidado').toggle('500');
  });
});
</script>
<?PHP
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $username =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
        $password =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
       
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
       $run = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
       $check = mysqli_num_rows($run);

       if ($check==0){
           echo "<script>alert('username or password is incorrect , try again! ')</script>";
           exit();
       }
       else {
           $_SESSION['username']=$username;
           echo "<script>alert('welcome doctor ')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.open('hospital_form.php','_self')</script>";
       }


    }
 include ('footer.php');
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I would be very appreciated for helping :)

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: You should clarify what you need help with. What are you trying to achieve, what is not working, do you get any errors?

Comment: thanks for replaying , this code work ,,  what I want is how to make access for different users in different pages . for example admin user has different pages than other user . I want to edit php code to be able to access as admin and normal user to go in different pages 
 wish I could explain well

Comment: You would need to check if the user is allowed to access the page, in the start of every page. Also, this kind of stuff is quite hard to do right, you will need more information than what can be given in one SO answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to fetch user_type from your DB. Also, it is not best practice to select all (*) from DB, be specific.

```
$sql = "SELECT username, password, user_type FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
```

Your check condition should check if true, not otherwise. You are checking if $num_rows is not 0. So if your mysqli_query() returns false, you will login the user? Thats not good. Check **if true -> login**

We gonna add header function to the code, so if user_type is admin it will redirect him to admin.php, if not, user will be redirected to index.php

Example of the above:

```
$run = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$check = mysqli_num_rows($run);

if ($check == 1){

    #fetch the information
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run);

    # Save username and user type
    $user_type = $row['user_type'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['user_type'] = $user_type;

    # Check is user is admin or not and redirect him
    if($user_type == 'admin') {

        header('Location: path/to/admin.php');

    } else {

        header('Location: path/to/index.php');

    }


} else {

    # No user found, redirect him back to login page
    header('Location: path/to/login.php');

}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help it shows the login page is that means

Comment: My bad, i forgot to add ; after $user_type = $row['user_type'] 

Ill edit the original answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help it shows the login page is that means  # No user found, redirect him back to login page
    header('Location: path/to/login.php');

Comment: It means check is not equal to 1 and therefore statement is false. It can be because of wrong username/password, no connection to database, etc. You need to make sure that other parts of code work and that they return expected values, you can always vardump values to see whats going on.

Comment: No problem. Please mark answer so you close the question.